# Same user with different name for Gmail and YouTube

Tags: gmail, youtube

How is it possible to have one username for Gmail for example `John 1` and the same user for YouTube but with other name, lets say `John 2`?

So if I send an email it will be from `John 1` and if I post comments on YouTube videos etc. `John 2` will be visible.

Answer (score 4):

You can only have one name per identity. You can create additional identities by either creating a new Google account, or by creating a brand account (new channel) within a Google account on https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher. You can move channels between identities via https://www.youtube.com/account_transfer_channel.

Comment: Under https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher I have 2 accounts. John 1 with email and all youtube subscriptions and John 2 with no subscription. So I can now transfer all my subscriptions (video channels, that are interesting for me) from John 1 to John 2. After it I can use John 1 for email communication and the information about new videos from John 2 will also be visible under my John 1 email?

Comment: yes, exactly. .